# How to test changing windows in webdriver.io?

Tags: electron, webdriver

I wrote an application consisting of two windows.
First, the first window is shown, when you click the button, the first window is deleted and the second one opens.
An error occurs when calling the test

```
     waitUntil condition failed with the following reason: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found
```

How to solve?

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const authButton = await authPageObject.authButton;
    await authButton.click();

    await browser.waitUntil(
      async () => {
        const uploadFileButton = await loaderPageObject.uploadFileButton;
        return uploadFileButton !== undefined;
      },
      { timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT },
    );

    const handles = await browser.getWindowHandles();
    await browser.switchToWindow(handles[1]);

    await dialogPageObject.showDialog([imagesFilePath]);

    const images = await loaderPageObject.imagesFileButton;
    await images.click();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve, i have to

1. Close first window (clikc io button) only once
2. Swicth to new window by webdriver api switchWindow

```js
before(async () => {
    const authButton = await authPageObject.authButton;
    await authButton.click();
    await browser.switchWindow("Загрузите товары");
  })
```